# Date picker for facebook application

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

hi i am developing a facebook application. i need two date picker in my application. Is there any date picker available. please help me...

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI has a wide selection of methods that can help you develop Web 2.0 applications. One of them is the Datepicker method. You can read about it at:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
Here is a sample implementation:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: i am developing my application using fbml. is it possible to use jquery in my application

Comment: @rose, absolutely. All you need is to load the jQuery Core Library, the jQuery UI library and the jQuery UI css on the <HEAD> part of your page then insert the code above to your page to have the working datepicker. The best way to start with jQuery UI is to download the jQuery UI package. That is a compressed file with a complete and easy to follow examples including the libraries and stylesheets you need to get started. It's even easier than learning pure javascript itself. If you can elarn javascript in a week you'll get a hang of jQuery in less than a day. Good luck to you.